# Find the angle between each set of the following planes. 1) $5x - 3y + 2z = 11$ and $x + 3y + 2z = -5$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the angle between each set of the following planes.

1) $5x - 3y + 2z = 11$ and $x + 3y + 2z = -5$

The $11$ and $-5$ I am confused on.

$n_1 = [5,-3,2]$ and $n_2 = [1,3,2]$

$\theta = cos^{-1}\frac{n_1 \cdot n_2}{|n_1||n_2|}$

$n_1 \cdot n_2 = 0$

so $\theta = cos^{-1}(0) = 90$

Comment: What’s confusing you about the constant terms? They just indicate that the planes have been shifted away from the origin by some amount, but their directions haven’t changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,  the normal to the plane $ax+by+cz=d$ is $(a,b,c)$.  Thus, since the dot product of the normals is zero, the planes are perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by amd in the comments, note that the angle between the given planes is the same for the planes shifted at the origin that is

- $5x - 3y + 2z = 0$
- $x + 3y + 2z = 0$

and since $n_1\cdot n_2=0$ the angle between them is $90°$.